# I want to disable screenshot functionality for my android air app

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to disable screenshot function for my android air 22 AS3,
live video streaming app like when we start Skype video calling in android phone screen recorder automatically stopped

Comment: That looks like too broad to me. Pleade include your code and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking the screenshot functionality is achieved in Android by setting the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE` to the main activity during it's creation, before anything is displayed.

Since AIR takes care of creating and starting the Activity of your app there's no way (that i know) to block that functionality. Setting the flag later through a Native Extension would be possible but I think it would be too late and would have no effect.

Would be a nice thing to be able to set up in the manifest ...